# Errors while installing mod_wsgi in python?

Tags: python, flask, pip, mod-wsgi

I was trying to install `mod_wsgi` , so i installed its prerequisites  .

- Python (3.7.4)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Build tool (2015) Microsoft
- Visual C++    2015-2019 Redistributable (14.23.27820)
- Xampp (for Apache 2.4)

But the on doing `pip install mod_wsgi` i got following errors

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install mod_wsgi
Collecting mod_wsgi
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/03/a3ed5abc2e66c82c40b
0735c2f819c898d136879b00be4f5537126b6a4a4/mod_wsgi-4.6.7.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mod-wsgi
  Running setup.py install for mod-wsgi ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\taha.tauqir\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\py
thon.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\
\TAHA~1.TAU\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_zkqbo33\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"'
; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\TAHA~1.TAU\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_zkqbo3
3\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);c
ode=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code,
__file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\TAHA~1.TAU\AppData\Local\
Temp\pip-record-4uoq0nq8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed
 --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\TAHA~1.TAU\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_zkqbo33\mod-ws
gi\
    Complete output (33 lines):
    c:\users\taha.tauqir\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils
\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi
    copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management
    copying src\server\management\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\se
rver\management
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\
mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mo
d_wsgi\server\management\commands
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\docs
    copying docs\_build\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\docs
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\images
    running build_ext
    building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\server
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe /c /nologo
 /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\xampp\apache/include -Ic:\users\taha.tauqir\appda
ta\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\taha.tauqir\appdata\loca
l\programs\python\python37-32\include /Tcsrc/server\mod_wsgi.c /Fobuild\temp.win
32-3.7\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi.obj
    mod_wsgi.c
    c:\users\taha.tauqir\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-_zkqbo33\mod-wsgi\src\se
rver\wsgi_apache.h(39): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ws2tcpip.h
': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\b
in\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\taha.tauqir\appdata\loc
al\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokeni
ze; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\TAHA~1.TAU\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-
_zkqbo33\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\TAHA~1.TAU\\AppData\
\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_zkqbo33\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
'"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'
"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C
:\Users\TAHA~1.TAU\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4uoq0nq8\install-record.txt' --
single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command outp
ut.
```

Comment: add vc++ to your path

Comment: using windows 32?

Comment: @SaiKrishna , I have already added "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin"  to my environment variable  for cl.exe & its windows 7 (64 bit)

Comment: looks like you have installed python for 32bit!!! can u check it once?

Comment: @SaiKrishna yes it was 32bit & i have installed 64 bits now , still same problem

Comment: and now install vc++ libraries again

Comment: buddy you are using windows 32bit!!! and if you are not sure right click on my computers and then press properties and see system type there

Comment: you using windows 32 bit system!! but you have installed vc++ for 64 bit

Comment: @SaiKrishna https://ibb.co/mRB5c0d here is the link of my pc properties , you can check it

Comment: then problem is with your vc++!! try downloading other version vc++,

Comment: Go to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi, download `mod_wsgi‑4.6.7+ap24vc15‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` (if 32bit windows) or `mod_wsgi‑4.6.7+ap24vc15‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` (if 64bit windows), run `pip install path\to\downloaded\mod_wsgi.whl`, enjoy.